# dcdrilldown with breadcrumb not having correct height size

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am using [dcdrilldown](http://www.designchemical.com/lab/jquery-drill-down-menu-plugin/examples/) with the version posted by @Tay on [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13477493/where-can-i-find-a-jquery-accordian-type-menu-or-get-this-one-working). It works fine when I use `linkType:'link'` but if I change it to `linkType:'breadcrumb'` it just does not size the height correctly and only show one "item".

Please check [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TLuBN/4/) to see that with `breadcrumb` it does not show "Cat 2" while with `link` it [works perfectly](http://jsfiddle.net/TLuBN/5/). I'd very much like to use breadcrumb but I can't find out where the bug lie.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script isn't setting the height properly on the `ul#drilldown-2` menu container. The menu choices are there, but the fixed height on the container is too small for them to show. The version you are using assumes that your top level menu only has one entry.

http://jsfiddle.net/TLuBN/8/

find this function:

```
   function findMaxHeight(element) {
        var maxIndex = undefined;
        $(element).each(function () {
            var val = parseInt($('> li', this).length);
            $(this).attr('rel', val);
            if (maxIndex === undefined || maxIndex < val) {
                maxIndex = val;
            }
        });
        if ($(element).find('li').length > maxIndex) {
            //the longest 'submenu' could be the root menu
            return 1;
        } else {
            return maxIndex;
        }
    }
```

and change the line that says `return 1;` to `return $(element).closest('.dd-menu').find('> li').length;` so it reads

```
   function findMaxHeight(element) {
        var maxIndex = undefined;
        $(element).each(function () {
            var val = parseInt($('> li', this).length);
            $(this).attr('rel', val);
            if (maxIndex === undefined || maxIndex < val) {
                maxIndex = val;
            }
        });
        if ($(element).find('li').length > maxIndex) {
            //the longest 'submenu' could be the root menu
            return $(element).closest('.dd-menu').find('> li').length;
        } else {
            return maxIndex;
        }
    }
```

and see if that's the desired behavior.

Comment: Perfect, exactly the solution I was looking for.